# Is this correct grammar?

Tags: grammar

Is this correct grammar? 
“Last year my wife and I clocked up twenty years here in this town”

Comment: It perhaps depends on what the verb "clock up" means. Did you not "clock-up twenty years" over a period of twenty years? How could you clock-up twenty years, during the course of last year? I don't think I would use "clock-up" here. Perhaps I'd say "Last year we completed twenty years in this town".

Answer (score 1):

"Last year my wife and I realised we had clocked up twenty years here in this town."

"By last year my wife and I had clocked up twenty years here in this town."

"Last year my wife and I celebrated clocking up twenty years here in this town."

Clocking up is the process of accumulating the time, so we should avoid implying it all happened in one year.